# Is it possible to "root" a Windows Phone device? What are the benefits?

Tags: 7.x, rooting

Android devices can be ["rooted"](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/how-do-i-root-my-device), allowing unrestricted access to the file system, tethering, extra hardware control, and more.

The Windows Phone operating system is not a Linux-based operating system, but does the same idea still apply? If so, what WP-specific things can be done once the device is "rooted"?

Comment: **Related:** The legality and/or scope of this question is being [discussed on meta](http://meta.windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/9/should-we-allow-questions-that-belong-to-the-gray-area).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Yes, with [WP7RootTools](http://www.wp7roottools.com/).

It gives you:

- registry-editor (with access to low level previously restricted parts of the registry)
- file-explorer with basic file-operations
- certificate-installer with write-access to the certificate-stores
- policy-editor

Note that Rooting is different then unlocking and custom ROMs.

Comment: As of December 2014, these tools only work for WP7.x not for WP8.x

Comment: Yes, that link is Windows Phone 7 specific.