# Is there a way to get terminal access on a WP7 device?

Tags: rooting

Does the WP7 support terminal access where I can actually run commands on the phone from my computer?

Similar to the Android Debug Bridge (ADB) which allows you to connect to the device and open a shell and run commands on the device itself.

While the ADB is a developer tool, there are a lot of non-developer related things you can do with it.

Comment: I would say "If you do, there would not be much commands to execute".

Answer (score 1):

**No** it is not possible to gain terminal access. However, you could try [rooting your device](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/17/is-it-possible-to-root-a-windows-phone-device-what-are-the-benefits).

### Do this at your own risk

Besides the obvious of possibly bricking your phone, you could loose carrier support and would be up a creek as they say.

Now that I think about it, I'm not event sure rooting gives you terminal access. There is an SDK supported for the tool. That might be what you are looking for.