# Unofficial tethering on Windows Phone

Tags: lumia, functionality, htc, internet-sharing

I'm currently looking to buy a Windows Phone (not sure about which one yet, probably a Nokia or HTC) and I'd like to know if unofficial tethering (without carrier support) is possible; either via USB (which is fine, it'll keep the phone charged) or Wi-Fi.

My carrier's plans are total ripoffs and they don't even have unlimited tethering plans (the most you can get is 1GB, which is about my weekly data usage), so "official" tethering isn't an option.

I've already looked at [this question](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/17/is-it-possible-to-root-a-windows-phone-device-what-are-the-benefits) which provides a way to "root" a Windows Phone and get access to the file system and registry, but I still don't know what registry key to change (or what files to modify) to enable tethering.

Thanks for your answers.

EDIT: I finally bought an Android phone; i'll accept the answer below though.

Comment: I used to USB tether my WP7 all the time with this method in the following link. I'm not sure if it works on WP8. http://mobilitydigest.com/windows-phone-7-tethers-you-can-do-it-now-heres-how/

Comment: Can you buy a contract-free sim unlocked phone and use it on your carrier? I got a Lumia directly from Nokia and was able to use the tethering. My understanding is that the carrier can remove it from devices that they sell, but I'm not sure if they can block it from phones which they did not sell.

Comment: @row1 I'm buying an used phone however it's SIM-unlocked.

Comment: @SteveH Thanks for your reply, however I think your solution is AT&T specific (it involves strange codes which I think depend on the carrier and the SIM card); anyway I won't risk buying a phone if the only way to tether is "that" (which may not work for me).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, developer unlocking a phone does not provide you with similar "rooting" abilities as other phones. If your carrier has locked the option to tether. So, unless you pay, your only option is to switch carriers.

Answer (score 0):

WiFi tethering is "in the box", and I've used it with success on both a HTC Titan and Nokia Lumia 800 - just look for "Internet Sharing" in Settings and turn it on when you want a mobile hotspot. If the option doesn't show, it may be that it is disabled by the network (for operator provided phones with customised firmware)