# Can Windows Phone 8 devices be rooted?

Tags: 8.0, rooting

Android can be [rooted](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/how-do-i-root-my-android-device) and even WP7 can be [rooted](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/17/is-it-possible-to-root-a-windows-phone-device-what-are-the-benefits). But is it possible to root devices running WP8?

Answer (score 3):

It's currently not possible to root a Windows Phone 8 device.

Keep an eye on the [XDA forums](http://forum.xda-developers.com/chef-central/windows-phone-7) for further developments.

Comment: I don't think OP was attempting to start on a discussion if it's theoretically possible to root a WP8 device, but if a working jailbreak is publicly available.

Comment: I don't think this is the correct place for it as it's a) too advanced for regular phone users and b) will invalidate their phone's warranty

Comment: Relevant: http://meta.windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/9/should-we-allow-questions-that-belong-to-a-gray-area